# CSS: div with concave and convex angles

Tags: html, css, radius, curves

I have to create a div with this shape without using images.
The background has to be transparent, that's the problem...

Is it possible?

Best regards

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnS51.png)

Comment: welcome to SO: could you show your efforts and share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zh78ysq/)

Code

```
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="294.12px" height="69.481px" viewBox="0 0 294.12 69.481" enable-
 background="new 0 0 294.12 69.481" xml:space="preserve">
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#00AEEF" 
 d="M43.2,0.001c69.264,0,138.528,0,207.72,0
 c21.312-0.216,19.944,69.048,43.2,69.48c-97.992,0-196.056,0-
 294.12,0C18.648,69.266,22.752-0.358,43.2,0.001z"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: OOH THANKS!! I didn't thought about using svg!! Best regards mate you solved all my problems